# Optimise reset form fields of different forms jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tabs with forms in each of them and on click of reset button, it resets form fields of that form only.

```
//Reset respective forms
    $('#thresholds .reset').on('click', function() {
        $('#thresholds').trigger("reset");
    });
    $('#attributes .reset').on('click', function() {
        $('#attributes').trigger("reset");
    });
    $('#rules .reset').on('click', function() {
        $('#rules').trigger("reset");
    });
    $('#events .reset').on('click', function() {
        $('#events').trigger("reset");
    });
```

#thresholds, #attributes, #rules, #events are the form IDs.

How can I optimise this for code repetition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge them like this:

```
$('#thresholds .reset, #attributes .reset, #rules .reset, #events .reset').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parents('form:first').trigger("reset");
});
```

Comment: You’re welcome, If it helped you, please [upvote and accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) Happy Coding! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can identify all `reset` click with `.reset` class and then select `closest from` of this button and apply `reset trigger`.

Please find below mentioned code. This will help you.

```
$('.reset').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('form').trigger('reset');
});
```

Check working example below.

```js
$('.reset').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('form').trigger('reset');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="thresholds">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="button"  class='reset' value="Reset" /> 
</form>

<form id="attributes">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="button"  class='reset' value="Reset" /> 
</form>


<form id="rules">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="button"  class='reset' value="Reset" /> 
</form>

<form id="events">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="button"  class='reset' value="Reset" /> 
</form>
```

Let me know if it not works.

Comment: This makes the code shorter but not more optimized, you are filtering every click every time  happening on the document level

Comment: @kapreski : You are right that it get filtered on every click. I have again updated my code.

Comment: Sorry, i dont know why it did not work for me. Here is my fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/inchrvndr/wthb5yfr/6/